# Pandas Rolling Function with Max

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'clicks': [i for i in range(1000)]})

# Calculate the max of the next 140 rows for each row
roll = df['clicks'].rolling(window=141, min_periods=1).max()
print(roll)
```

Somehow it doesnt return the expected output:

```
0        141.0
1        142.0
2        143.0
3        144.0
4        145.0
```

But it outputs:

```
0        0.0
1        1.0
2        2.0
3        3.0
4        4.0
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Because of  `min_periods=1`

Comment: Where's the rest of the output? Do you want 999 or NaN for the final rows? or something else? Please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341) with minimal data (say, maybe, 6 rows with a window of 3), or at least show the truncated output for this data. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and check out [ask] for more tips, like how to write a good title. You can [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to shift it by 140 rows forward so that the window ***includes the next 140 rows***, and not just the first, second, third etc leading up to 999.

```
# Calculate the rolling max of the next 140 rows for each row
roll = df['clicks'].shift(-140).rolling(window=141, min_periods=1).max()
```

Comment: Great - Thank you! And how would I do it for the other way round if I would like to identify the min amount?

Comment: You'd replace it with a `.min()` instead of `.max()`.